# Add geom_ribbon to reshape2 data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame (df) in the format

```
  Date          Cs.137 In.111 I.123  I.131     X99m.Tc min    max
1 2013-01-03    8.2    6.49   6.97   10.5      15      8.294  7.87930
2 2013-01-04    8.1    6.47   6.94   10.5      15      8.293  7.87835
3 2013-01-07    8.1    6.48   6.96   10.5      15      8.292  7.87740
4 2013-01-08    8.1    6.43   6.91   10.5      15      8.291  7.87645
5 2013-01-09    8.1    6.49   6.92   10.5      15      8.291  7.87645
6 2013-01-10    8.1    6.51   6.95   10.5      15      8.290  7.87550
```

I want to plot the measured activities of various isotopes over several dates as  a scatter plot. To do this I reshape the data

`plot_Data <- melt(df[,c(1,2:6)], id="Date", value.name="Activity", variable.name="Isotope")`

```
  Date        Isotope     Activity
1 2013-01-03  Cs.137      8.2
2 2013-01-04  Cs.137      8.1
3 2013-01-07  Cs.137      8.1
4 2013-01-08  Cs.137      8.1
5 2013-01-09  Cs.137      8.1
6 2013-01-10  Cs.137      8.1
```

I then plot this using `melt` from `reshape2`

`p <- ggplot(plot_Data, aes(x=Date, y=Activity, col=Isotope)) + geom_point()+ theme_bw()`
[image]

However, the I also want to show a geom_ribbon to highlight the allowed range for Cs-137 activities (given by min and max in the original data frame). I can create such a ribbon on its own using

`m <- ggplot(df) + geom_ribbon(data=df, aes(x=Date,ymin=min, ymax = max), alpha = 0.2, fill='blue')`

However, this is using the original frame pre_melted data frame.

When I try `p + geom_ribbon(data=df, aes(x=Date,ymin=min, ymax = max), alpha = 0.2, fill='blue')` I get the error message `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Activity' not found`

How can I overlay the ribbon on the original image?

Here is the original data_frame from which the remaining data can be reconstructed
`structure(list(Date = structure(c(15708, 15709, 15712, 15713, 
15714, 15715, 15716, 15719, 15720, 15721, 15722, 15723, 15726, 
15727, 15729, 15730, 15733, 15734, 15735, 15736, 15740, 15741, 
15743, 15747, 15748, 15749, 15750, 15751, 15754, 15755, 15756, 
15757, 15758, 15761, 15762, 15764, 15765, 15768, 15769, 15770, 
15771, 15772), class = "Date"), Cs.137 = c(8.2, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 
8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 
8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.2, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8, 
8.2, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1), 
    In.111 = c(6.49, 6.47, 6.48, 6.43, 6.49, 6.51, 6.5, 6.47, 
    6.48, 6.4, 6.48, 6.48, 6.48, 6.49, 6.49, 6.47, 6.48, 6.48, 
    6.5, 6.47, 6.49, 6.55, 6.46, 6.49, 6.48, 6.48, 6.46, 6.48, 
    6.49, 6.44, 6.49, 6.46, 6.45, 6.46, 6.46, 6.43, 6.49, 6.47, 
    6.45, 6.43, 6.44, 6.44), I.123 = c(6.97, 6.94, 6.96, 6.91, 
    6.92, 6.95, 6.93, 6.92, 6.93, 7, 6.97, 6.96, 6.96, 6.94, 
    6.98, 6.97, 6.95, 6.95, 6.94, 6.96, 6.97, 7.01, 6.92, 7, 
    6.98, 6.97, 6.91, 6.99, 6.95, 6.88, 6.96, 6.91, 6.91, 6.93, 
    6.94, 6.94, 6.97, 6.93, 6.93, 6.93, 6.96, 6.94), I.131 = c(10.5, 
    10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.8, 10.5, 
    10.6, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 
    10.6, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 
    10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.4, 10.5, 10.4, 
    10.5), X99m.Tc = c(15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
    15, 15.1, 15, 15, 15.1, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15.1, 15, 15.1, 15, 
    15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 14.9, 15, 
    15, 15, 15, 15, 15), Exp_Act = c(8.294, 8.293, 8.292, 8.291, 
    8.291, 8.29, 8.29, 8.288, 8.288, 8.287, 8.287, 8.286, 8.285, 
    8.284, 8.283, 8.283, 8.281, 8.28, 8.28, 8.279, 8.277, 8.277, 
    8.276, 8.274, 8.273, 8.273, 8.272, 8.272, 8.27, 8.27, 8.269, 
    8.269, 8.268, 8.266, 8.266, 8.265, 8.264, 8.263, 8.262, 8.262, 
    8.261, 8.261), Exp_Act_0.95 = c(7.8793, 7.87835, 7.8774, 
    7.87645, 7.87645, 7.8755, 7.8755, 7.8736, 7.8736, 7.87265, 
    7.87265, 7.8717, 7.87075, 7.8698, 7.86885, 7.86885, 7.86695, 
    7.866, 7.866, 7.86505, 7.86315, 7.86315, 7.8622, 7.8603, 
    7.85935, 7.85935, 7.8584, 7.8584, 7.8565, 7.8565, 7.85555, 
    7.85555, 7.8546, 7.8527, 7.8527, 7.85175, 7.8508, 7.84985, 
    7.8489, 7.8489, 7.84795, 7.84795), Exp_Act_1.05 = c(8.7087, 
    8.70765, 8.7066, 8.70555, 8.70555, 8.7045, 8.7045, 8.7024, 
    8.7024, 8.70135, 8.70135, 8.7003, 8.69925, 8.6982, 8.69715, 
    8.69715, 8.69505, 8.694, 8.694, 8.69295, 8.69085, 8.69085, 
    8.6898, 8.6877, 8.68665, 8.68665, 8.6856, 8.6856, 8.6835, 
    8.6835, 8.68245, 8.68245, 8.6814, 8.6793, 8.6793, 8.67825, 
    8.6772, 8.67615, 8.6751, 8.6751, 8.67405, 8.67405)), row.names = c(NA, 
-42L), .Names = c("Date", "Cs.137", "In.111", "I.123", "I.131", 
"X99m.Tc", "Exp_Act", "Exp_Act_0.95", "Exp_Act_1.05"), class = "data.frame")`

Thanks

Comment: What is the allowed range? Is it the range of values of Cs.137 in your data frame? Can you paste the output from `dput(head(plot_Data))` so we can recreate your data in R? Thanks

Comment: Try un-mapping the `y` aesthetic in `geom_ribbon` by setting it to `NULL`.

Comment: @SimonO101 Output from dput is `structure(list(Date = structure(c(15708, 15709, 15712, 15713, 
15714, 15715), class = "Date"), Isotope = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Cs.137", "In.111", "I.123", "I.131", 
"X99m.Tc"), class = "factor"), Activity = c(8.2, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 
8.1, 8.1)), .Names = c("Date", "Isotope", "Activity"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
` I have edited the question to give allowed range - basically min and max of initial data frame

Comment: @joran With `p + geom_ribbon(data=df, aes(x=Date,y=NULL,ymin=min, ymax = max), alpha = 0.2, fill='blue')` I get the following error, `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Isotope' not found`. When I un-map the col aesthetic I get `Error in data.frame(x = c(15708, 15709, 15712, 15713, 15714, 15715, 15716,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 42, 0`

Comment: Well, un-mapping the aesthetics was unquestionably your first problem and needed to be done. The subsequent errors we can't really help with unless you give us something reproducible. FWIW, simply unmapping both aesthetics cause your plot code to run w/out error using just the data you've provided.

Comment: @joren, How can I pass reproducible code into the question. i.e the initial data frame?

Comment: @joren question edited with initial data frame. Thanks SimonO101

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, the data you posted has no columns called `min` and `max`, however I found the relevant columns and changed the name. you can then make your second df for the ribbon using aggregate like this...

```
mydf <- aggregate( cbind(min , max) ~ Date, data = df , FUN = mean )
```

You can then use this to plot the data like so....

```
p <- ggplot( NULL )+
  geom_point( data = plot_Data , aes( x = Date , y = value , col = variable ) )+
  geom_ribbon( data = mydf , aes( x = Date , ymin = min , ymax = max ), alpha = 0.2 , fill='blue' )+
  theme_bw()

print(p)
```

[image]

Is this what you were expecting?

Comment: min and max change by a small amount with date. This gomes from the data frame df, column names min and max

Comment: I changed the names of min and max on the post to tidy up the formating. This is perfect, thank you

Comment: This has been a very informative post, I tried repeatedly to get ggplot to use geom_point and geom_line in conjunction with geom_ribbon (although all mapping from separate df's) and failed hopelessly. Creating a null ggplot object first and then mapping the data and aes within the geom allows this to work. Not sure why though....

Answer (score 1):

The issue is (after you un-map those two aesthetics) that `ggplot` is getting confused by your column names, `min` and `max`. Those happen to be functions as well. Just rename them to `ymin` and `ymax`.

I should add that I'm not entirely certain why ggplot was getting confused by the column names on your full data, but not when I just copy+pasted your abbreviated data (although in the latter case the resulting plot was sort of nonsensical). But the occassional weird argument parsing issue is sort of something you have to live with in ggplot2-land.